# Can a model referred by a foreign key have its own foreign key to refer some other model?

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I want to make a model of school under which using foreignkey I can refer to all the students.. now the students could have there medical history and counselling history.. I want medical model and councelling model to be reffered by students Id.

The plan is to make a multi school model where students can be reffered by there school name but all the students have there own medical and counselling history.

Please explain how to achieve this in django by python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    .......
  
  class Student(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     ...........
     school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.setNull)

  class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.cascade)
     .................
```

and the same for the counseling Model

Comment: But sir as I was talking about multischool site.. can I restrict a user related to certain school to edit only models related to that school.. like if there are many schools the councellor of certain school can only add, delete, edit councelling details of the students of that particular school only.. please guide sir . Thnkyou

Comment: Will they edit from django-admin or your views, if it is your views then sure you can create a filter on school as follows `Students.objects.filter(school_id=request.user.scholl_id)`

Comment: they will edit from views sir. thankyou for your time.